# Stop company-lsp from completing function arguments

Tags: python, company-mode, lsp-mode

I try to configure `lsp-mode` and `company-lsp` with `python-language-server` for python autocompletion, but when I choose completion candidate it completes with function arguments. How can I prevent this behaviour?

For example for function

```
def foo(arg1, arg2):
    ...
```

It will autocomplete like

```
foo(arg1, arg2)
```

I tried to set `(setq lsp-enable-snippet nil)` but it didn't help

Answer (score 3):

There are actually two variables that drive this behavior.

You tried the first one, `lsp-enable-snippet` and it didn't work. This means that the culprit is probably `company-lsp`, which engages in a similar behavior and uses a variable that is nearly identical, `company-lsp-enable-snippet`.

Try disabling that with `(setq company-lsp-enable-snippet nil)` and see if that does the trick .

As an aside, when I struggle with a problem like this (where I have a suspicion there is a tangential/related mode driving the behavior), I try to looking for similarly named variables or variables that contain a reference to the behavior/feature/setting at hand. It's not a perfect heuristic, but it is how I found out about company's complementing behavior to lsp mode as answer above. If you have a feeling a problem is of this nature, next time try using `C-h v` and searching for the culprit variable.